# What am I missing in my solution? Convex Hull Finding Algorithm

Tags: java, convex-hull

I have been racking my brain around this problem for days now... I can't see what my algorithm could possibly be missing. This is the problem [here.](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=622)

From what I gather I am getting the points in a somewhat circular ccw order. So I've implemented a version of the graham scan that goes through looking to find the convex hull by ensuring it is using points that always give right-hand turns.

My algorithm works for all given test input and all input I can come up for it but it just won't get accepted by the online judge which is what is required for the assignment to be 'complete'.

Anyways, here is my code I would be forever in your debt if someone can find what I'm missing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {

public Main() {}

public void handlePoints(Point[] points) throws Exception {
    int m = 1;
    Vector<Point> convexHull = new Vector<Point>();
    // This is THE ONLY gaurunteed point to be in the hull - and it is the lowest left point so that's ok. 
    convexHull.add(points[0]);
    // Can be removed if ill-suited. 
    convexHull.add(points[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < points.length; i++) {
        // Find the next valid point on the hull. 
        while (counterClockWise(convexHull.elementAt(m-1), convexHull.elementAt(m), points[i]) <= 0) {
            convexHull.removeElementAt(m);
            if (m > 1) {
                m -= 1;
            }
            // All points are colinear
            else if (i == points.length - 1) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                convexHull.add(points[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
        convexHull.add(points[i]);
        m++;
    }   
    if (convexHull.size() <= 3) {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    String test = "" + convexHull.size() + '\n';
    for (Point p : convexHull) {
        test += p.x + " " + p.y + '\n';
    }
    System.out.print(test);
}

// Simply calculated whether or not the 3 points form a countedClockWise turn.
public int counterClockWise(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    return ((p2.x - p1.x) * (p3.y - p1.y)) - ((p2.y - p1.y) * (p3.x - p1.x));
}

// Rearranges the array to maintain its order but be started and ended by the point with the lowest y value
private static Point[] moveLowestToFront(Point[] array) {
    // Rearrange for y:
    int lowestY = 99999;
    int lowestIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].y < lowestY) {
            lowestY = array[i].y;
            lowestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    // Scan through again to see if there are any competing low-y values. 
    int lowestX = 99999;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].y == lowestY) {
            if (array[i].x < lowestX) {
                lowestX = array[i].x;
                lowestIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }
    Point[] rearrangedPoints = new Point[array.length];
    int j = 0;
    // Take from low to end cutting off repeated start point. 
    for (int i = lowestIndex; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        rearrangedPoints[j] = array[i];
        j++;
    }
    // Throw the remaining and put them at the end.
    for (int i = 0; i < lowestIndex; i++) {
        rearrangedPoints[j] = array[i];
        j++;
    }
    // End the array with the repeated first point. 
    rearrangedPoints[array.length - 1] = array[lowestIndex];
    return rearrangedPoints;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Main convexHullFinder = new Main();
    int numDataSets = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(numDataSets);
    for (int z = 0; z < numDataSets; z++) {
        int numPoints = sc.nextInt();
        Vector<Point> points = new Vector<Point>();
        // Read in all the points for this set. 
        points.add(new Point(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt()));
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++) {
            Point p = new Point(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());
            // Remove repeated points. 
            if (p.x < 0 || p.y < 0) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            if ( (p.x == points.elementAt(j-1).x) && (p.y == points.elementAt(j-1).y) ) {}
            else {
                points.add(p);
                j++;
            }
        }
        Point[] reducedPoints = points.toArray(new Point[points.size()]);

        // Rearrange the set to start and end on the lowest Y point. 
        reducedPoints = moveLowestToFront(reducedPoints);

        if (numPoints >= 3) {
            convexHullFinder.handlePoints(reducedPoints);
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        try { 
            System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
}

class Point {
public int x;
public int y;

public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't use the `homework` tag, [it has been deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: @Alex I suggest you to post this question in morning time ie PST. Some of the highly experience coders can give you some nice information on it as they are available by that time.

Comment: do you know why your homework has been rejected?

Comment: When implementing this algorithm, a. triple check that the right turn algorithm is right, b. ensure that the points are sorted lexicographically, c. check that you are actually creating both hulls, upper and lower by going through the points both forwards and backwards, d. ensure that you are removing a point from each section of the hull, this is needed to avoid duplicating hull points, as both the upper and lower sections will have the same first and last points.

Comment: Oh, I'm also not sure you should be throwing exceptions if the hull size is less than 3, as that just means the hull is made up of all the points.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, the points are sorted such that Graham Scan applies. Therefore, I think your stack operation (handlePoints) is probably not right.

I'm more used to Andrew's algorithm (a modification of Graham Scan), but I'm fairly sure you shouldn't be adding points to the convex hull both inside and outside of the while loop. The reason being I'm fairly sure the purpose of the while loop remains the same regardless of which algorithm is used. It's to remove invalid points from the convex hull. However, there's a chance that you're adding points during the while loop.

I'm not sure that's all that needs fixed though, but I don't have anything set up to run Java at the moment.